# Setting up Rails routes based on QueryString

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, query-string

I've seen similar questions on this, but not quite what I'm looking for...
Forgetting for a moment the *wisdom* of doing this, is it *possible* to do this?...

```
/object/update/123?o=section    # ==> route to SectionController#update
/object/update/456?o=question   # ==> route to QuestionController#update
```

...and if so, how would that be done?

Comment: I only see redirect_ti options in controller in this case

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you're using Rails 3+, you can use an "Advanced Constraint" (read more about them at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

Here's how to solve your example:

```
module SectionConstraint
  extend self

  def matches?(request)
    request.query_parameters["o"] == "section"
  end
end

module QuestionConstraint
  extend self

  def matches?(request)
    request.query_parameters["o"] == "question"
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match "/object/update/:id" => "section#update", :constraints => SectionConstraint
  match "/object/update/:id" => "question#update", :constraints => QuestionConstraint
end
```

Comment: Where, in which folder should this module be written? I am a newbie to RoR.

Answer (score 12):

More concise than [@moonmaster9000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065899/moonmaster9000)'s answer for `routes.rb` only:

```
match "/object/update/:id" => "section#update", 
  :constraints => lambda { |request| request.params[:o] == "section" }
match "/object/update/:id" => "question#update", 
  :constraints => lambda { |request| request.params[:o] == "question" }
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside the question of whether it is wise to do so, the answer to "is this possible" is 'yes':

```
class QueryControllerApp
  def self.call(env)
    controller_name = env['QUERY_STRING'].split('=').last
    controller = (controller_name.titleize.pluralize + "Controller").constantize
    controller.action(:update).call(env)
  rescue NameError
    raise "#{controller_name} is an invalid parameter"
  end
end

MyRailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
  put 'posts/update/:id' =>  QueryControllerApp
end
```

Basically the route mapper can accept any Rack application as an endpoint. Our simple app parses the query string, builds the controller name and calls the ActionController method `action` (which is itself a Rack application). Not shown: how to deal with query strings with any format other than `'o=<controller_name>'`

Comment: As best I can tell this is the only way to "redirect" without having the side effect of having your query string stripped off.  Thank you @zetetic

Comment: Instead of `.split` to get at the query sting, I would use: `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(env["QUERY_STRING"])`