# Rails route to action depending on parameter

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a little search with rails.
The search should work like /search?q="[query]"

Is there a way to rout requests without the "?q=" parameter to the index action and otherwise to the search action?
I have tried this but it does not work.

```
  controller :search do
    get ':index' => :index
    get ':index?:query' => :search
  end
```

Comment: You should have a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888263/setting-up-rails-routes-based-on-querystring

Answer (score 0):

In your action just add

```
redirect_to root_path and return unless params[:q]
```