# Playframework routes with different query parameters

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have two methods in my search controller

searchBoundingBox - does bounding box search and requires the bounding box latitude and longitude values.
search - does distance search (does distance based search from the center point).

I have defined my two routes in route file as below.

```
#Search
#bounding box
GET     /search                             controllers.Search.searchBoundingBox(swLatitude:java.lang.String,swLongitude:java.lang.String, neLatitude:java.lang.String,neLongitude:java.lang.String)

# distance based
GET     /search                             controllers.Search.search(latitude:java.lang.String,longitude:java.lang.String, offset:java.lang.Integer?=0,distance:java.lang.Integer?=50, limit:java.lang.Integer?=10)
```

But when I create a query in the 2nd route (distance based) it is not resolved.

Any workarounds !!!( Note if I change the order of the routes then the bounding box searches fails)

Comment: How the router can guess which route is the right ? They avec no args (like /search/:latitute/:longitude). Routes cannot be identified by queryString parameters

Comment: okay, is that play route limitation. i think you can do this in ROR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888263/setting-up-rails-routes-based-on-querystring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal when two routes uses the same method (`GET`) and same path (`/search`) only first is used, there's no derogation from this rule.

First solution given by **Schleichardt** is possible however for best safety you should strictly control types of inputs.

Second, much faster and much easier solution is... just paths of routes unique ie:

```
#bounding box
GET     /search/bound/:swLatitude/:swLongitude/:neLatitude/:neLongitude      controllers.Search.searchBoundingBox(swLatitude: String, swLongitude: String, neLatitude: String, neLongitude: String)

# distance based
GET     /search/distance/:latitude/:longitude   controllers.Search.search(latitude: String, longitude: String, offset: Int?=0, distance: Int?=50, limit: Int?=10)
```

Btw you don't need give full path to common types like `String`, `Integer`, etc. if your Java method uses an Integer type construct routes with Scala `Int`.

Comment: conceptually, the path on REST best defines entities or relationships, there's no hierarchy on latitude vs longitude

Answer (score 5):

If you are forced to use query params you can use one action for both searches as a workaround:

```
GET     /search   controllers.Search.search
```

and fetch the query parameters yourself:

Scala:

```
def search = Action { request =>
     val latitude = request.queryString.getOrElse("latitude", Seq()).headOption.getOrElse("default")
```

Java:

```
public static Result search() {
        String latitude = request().queryString().get("latitude")[0];//of course check if param is in map
```

So you can split the action:

```
if(latitude != null)
   searchWithoutBoundingBox()
else
   searchBoundingBox()
```

You see this is not a nice and typesafe API so it's better to follow Julien's and biesior's approach.

Comment: this is very ugly, but we ended up using something like this