# Rails - Redirect URL with params (routes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, haml, param

I'm trying to create a redirect for anyone that has parameters in a certain url, to the homepage. I currently have this in my routes:

`match "/pr?campaign=#{'params[:campaign]'}" => redirect("/")`

but it's not recognising it properly, if i put `/pr?campaign=test` into the url I get a page not found..

Comment: assuming you want to route based on the query string take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888263/setting-up-rails-routes-based-on-querystring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question, maybe try this:

```
match '/pr'           => 'controller#action'           # responds to no additional params
match '/pr/:campaign' => 'another_controller#action'   # responds to another param.
```

So, `/pr` will be received by `controller#action`, but `/pr/test` will be received by `another_controller#action` and receive *test* as `params[:campaign]`

**Edit (actual solution to this problem):**

```
match '/pr' => redirect('/')
```

Comment: sorry i've explained it really badly, `/pr` isn't a page, it's just a link with some params, I want them to redirect to the home page straight away, surely i wouldn't need to involve controllers?

Comment: `match '/pr' => redirect('/')` will redirect `/pr` and `/pr?campaign=test` to `/`

Comment: well.. that was much simpler than i thought! Thanks!